# InternetExplorerDriver getPageSource() is returning a different string than FirefoxDriver

Tags: selenium, webdriver

I am new to Selenium and wonder if someone could point me in the right direction.

I am trying to get the page source of a page, but I notice IE driver returns something
different than FirefoxDriver.

Also, the String returned by InternetExplorerDriver.getPageSource() is different than the one i see if i click view page source on IE.

I am running IE 8 and Firefox 22.

For sample on this page: `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16455217/webdriver-save-the-location-of-the-id-in-the-page`

When I called getPageSource(), IE returned something like this.

```
"<HTML><HEAD><TITLE>selenium - Webdriver / Save the location of the ID in the page - Stack Overflow</TITLE><LINK rel="shortcut icon" href="https://cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/favicon.ico"><LINK rel="apple-touch-icon image_src" href="https://cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/apple-touch-icon.png">
```

While Firefox returned this.

```
"<!DOCTYPE html>
```

```
<title>selenium - Webdriver / Save the location of the ID in the page - Stack Overflow</title>
<link href="https://cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" />
<link href="https://cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/apple-touch-icon.png" rel="apple-touch-icon image_src" />
```

Is there a way for IEDriver to return a pageSource in the same way as FirefoxDriver?

Answer (score 6):

No, that's because the `getPageSource` method does not return the page source as it would do manually in your browser but returns a text representation of the DOM. [Javadoc of `getPageSource`](http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver.html#getPageSource%28%29) explains it better:

> `java.lang.String getPageSource()`
>
> Get the source of the last loaded page. If the page has been modified
>   after loading (for example, by Javascript) there is no guarantee that
>   the returned text is that of the modified page. Please consult the
>   documentation of the particular driver being used to determine whether
>   the returned text reflects the current state of the page or the text
>   last sent by the web server. **The page source returned is a
>   representation of the underlying DOM**: do not expect it to be formatted
>   or escaped in the same way as the response sent from the web server.
>   Think of it as an artist's impression.