# Using selenium WebEngine to get .js file content (when saved .js file is in pagename_files folder)

Tags: java, javascript, parsing, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I need to parse page. I couldn't find element I need in html source, but found it in .js file. When I save page with firefox(and choose complete webpage) it is stored in pagename_files folder. I want to get this .js file content for further parsing. Now I use this code:

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.get("link");
String pageSource = driver.getPageSource();
```

But I also need to get the same way content of .js file.
It always the same js file - initItemDetail.js

Googled it but no success, I really need help. Figthing for 3 days now with this dynamic element which I need to parse. The only good thing is: I learned a bit of javafx and selenium doing this.

Comment: Can't you simply do `driver.get("http://path-to-js-file.js")` ?

Comment: Be also aware that `getPageSource` doesn't return the source but a representation of the DOM in case of an HTML page. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17734065/internetexplorerdriver-getpagesource-is-returning-a-different-string-than-fire/17737795#17737795